# Is the question right?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

> Is this question solvable?
>
> I think  the required race time is not given. So it is quite
>   impossible to evaluate it.

Comment: Juan runs $1.5$ times faster than Jeremy is the point.

Comment: As it ends up, the answer will be the same whatever the actual race time happens to be.  Keep in mind that at any particular time, the distance traveled is proportional to the speed of travel.

Comment: You can figure out the distance run by Juan by $\frac{3}{4}\pi d$. When Juan is at this distance, Jeremy is at $\frac{1}{1.5}$ as far, round the circle. You can find both these lengths and thus, the difference in distance.

Comment: "$1.5$ times faster" is an abominable usage.  Some people use that expression to mean $1.5$ times as fast.  But that going $0.8$ times as fast would be going "$0.8$ times faster" even though it's actually slower.

Comment: @Michael Hardy you're right; does it mean 1.5x or 2.5x? Also I'm going to have to close that quotation mark."

Comment: @MichaelHardy:  "three times slower" is even worse  IMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to know how much time has passed.  You already know their speeds relative to one another.  If Juan is $3/4$ of the way around the track, Jeremy should be halfway around.  Can you solve it from there?

Comment: Ihave got this, $(1/4) \pi -(1/2) \pi = (1/4) \pi$, Then which of the options will be matched?

Comment: Another problem is that, do i have to use the vector quantity, i mean the shortest distance?

Comment: @ComplexGuy It must want the straight line distance, otherwise answers would involve $\pi$.  However, it shouldn't be hard to calculate this distance.  Now that I look at the problem though, it looks like Michael Hardy might have a point in his comments, which would make the problem much harder.

Comment: Got it :)  The question should have mentioned the "shorted distance. "